# Wicket multiple checkbox Issue

Tags: hibernate, wicket

I'm new to wicket-hibernate development. I have the following scenario but I'm not sure how to achieve it through wicket.

I have a role table which contains following values

## Role

## ID        description

1         Purchaser

2         Notifier

3         EmailRecipient

I have a PersonRelation table which contains following details

## Personrelation

## Id       people

1          112

2          113

Here people is a foreign key that refers to people table. A many to many relationship exists between peoplerelation and role table.

A wicket form contains the 'Role table description' as check-boxes in the front end. Whenever user clicks on the checkboxes the many to many relationship table should be updated accordingly. Please let me know how to achieve it through wicket-spring-hibernate. Appreciate your help to solve this issue.

PFA the code for hibernate classes.

---

```
     @Entity
public class PeopleRelation implements DaoFunPortalObject {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "PeopleRelation_id")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "People")
private People people;

@Column(name = "relationship")
private String relation;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(
    name = "PeopleRelation_Role",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "PeopleRelation_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "Role_id")}  
)   
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

public PeopleRelation() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public People getPeople() {
    return people;
}

public void setPeople(People people) {
    this.people = people;
}

public String getRelationship() {
    return relation;
}

public void setRelationship(String relation) {
    this.relation = relation;
}

public String getRelation() {
    return relation;
}

public void setRelation(String relation) {
    this.relation = relation;
}


public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

}

---

```
@Entity
public class Role implements DaoFunPortalObject{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "Role_id")
private Long id;

private String description;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
private Set<PeopleRelation> peopleRelations = new HashSet<PeopleRelation>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Set<PeopleRelation> getPeopleRelations() {
    return peopleRelations;
}

public void setPeopleRelations(Set<PeopleRelation> peopleRelations) {
    this.peopleRelations = peopleRelations;
}
```

}

---

Wicket front end

```
        personForm.add(new DropDownChoice<String>("state",
            new PropertyModel<String>(people, "state"), statesList));
    personForm.add(new TextField<String>("zip",
            new PropertyModel<String>(people, "zip")));
    personForm.add(new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String>(
    "roles", new Model(roleSelect), roleList));
```

Comment: To me it is not clear, what the checkbox task is.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate you have to have a new session to be able to retrieve and save data. Usually in a web application you open a session at the beginning of the request and close it at the end. Spring has an OpenSessionInViewFilter which is a servlet filter that should be placed in the filter chain before the wicket application. It opens the hibernate session at the beginning of the request and closes it at the end. All of this happens transparently to your application code.

In your question you were not clear about what problem you were having. Is your solution causing an error message? If so what is it?

Hope this helps!